# Horizontal Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I am working on a horizontal navigation bar for my website where upon clicking 
on a button in the top corner,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/USPzf.jpg

additional options appear,

and then upon hovering over the additional options, more options appear:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7GWI.jpg

However, as seen in the screenshots, 'Option', 'Option2' and 'Option3' are not inline with each other, which is what I am aiming to achieve. Here is the HTML:

```css
    #menu{
    }
    #ulmain{
    }
    #limain{
     list-style:none;
    }
    #ulsub {
     visibility:hidden;
    }
    #lisub{
     list-style:none;
     display:inline;
    }
    #ulmain:hover #ulsub{
     visibility:visible;
    }
    #ulsubsub {
     visibility:hidden;
    }
    #lisub:hover #ulsubsub{
     visibility:visible;
    }
    #lisubsub{
     list-style:none;
     display:inline;
    }
    #menu a{
     background-color:pink;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    #ulmain, #ulsub{
     display:inline;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
      <title>New Menu</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="menu">
       <ul id="ulmain">
        <li id="limain"><a id="amain" href="#">Menu</a>
         <ul id="ulsub">
          <li id="lisub"><a id="asub" href="#">Option</a>
           <ul id="ulsubsub">
            <li id="lisubsub"><a href="#">Sub-Option</a></li>
            <li id="lisubsub"><a href="#">Sub-Option2</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="lisub"><a href="#">Option2</a>
           <ul id="ulsubsub">
            <li id="lisubsub"><a href="#">Sub-Option3</a></li>
            <li id="lisubsub"><a href="#">Sub-Option4</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="lisub"><a href="#">Option3</a>
           <ul id="ulsubsub">
            <li id="lisubsub"><a href="#">Sub-Option5</a></li>
            <li id="lisubsub"><a href="#">Sub-Option6</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

How can I get 'Option', 'Option2', and 'Option3' inline? Thanks.

Comment: Have a read here: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ and then adjust your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
 #menu{
    }
    #ulmain{
    }
    #limain{
        list-style:none;
    }
    #ulsub {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    #lisub{
        list-style:none;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #ulmain:hover #ulsub{
        visibility:visible;
    }
    #ulsubsub {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    #lisub:hover #ulsubsub{
        visibility:visible;
    }
    #lisubsub{
        list-style:none;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #menu a{
        background-color:pink;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #ulmain, #ulsub{
        display:block;
    }
```

Preety much the same, you made ul display as inline, make them block and also make the li as display:inline-block;

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
As suggested, I added 'inline-block' to '#lisub' but decided against adding it to '#lisubsub' as it looked better without it in '#lisubsub'. 'Option', 'Option2', and 'Option3' are now inline. However, would it be possible to make the 'Options' go inline with 'Menu'?